# Ubuntu multi monitor not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Mac Pro system with dual upgraded NVidia 8800 GT cards.  I'm running quad monitors.  The center one is a 30" at 2560x1600 and is flanked on both sides with dual 24" 1920x1200 offset down 300 pixels to match the physical arrangement.  Finally, I have a Cintiq 21UX at 1600x1200 off to the right side.

Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, then ran all updates, and finally grabbed the updated NVidia driver.  Configured `xorg.conf` via the NVidia utility, then did simple renames so I know what I was looking at.  However, I can't get the configuration to properly work.  The most I can get is two monitors going but as soon as I try to enable three, things start getting weird, rendering in the wrong place, ghost mouse clicks half a screen away from where they really are.  If I try four monitors, then the UI doesn't even come up... just the desktop with Nautilus menus but no launcher, clock or anything else.

Here's my `xorg.conf` file. Anyone see anything wrong here? I don't and I've been battling with this for the past eight hours.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "AppleScreen" 1920 0
    Screen      1  "RightGatewayScreen" 4480 300
    Screen      2  "CintiqScreen" 6400 900
    Screen      3  "LeftGatewayScreen" 0 300
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "VideoCard1A"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8800 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "VideoCard1B"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8800 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "VideoCard2A"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8800 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "VideoCard2B"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8800 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "AppleMonitor"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Apple Cinema HD"
    HorizSync       49.3 - 98.5
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "RightGatewayMonitor"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Gateway FPD2485W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "LeftGatewayMonitor"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Gateway FPD2485W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "CintiqMonitor"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "WAC Cintiq21UX"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 92.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "AppleScreen"
    Device         "VideoCard1A"
    Monitor        "AppleMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "RightGatewayScreen"
    Device         "VideoCard1B"
    Monitor        "RightGatewayMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "LeftGatewayScreen"
    Device         "VideoCard2A"
    Monitor        "LeftGatewayMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "CintiqScreen"
    Device         "VideoCard2B"
    Monitor        "CintiqMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

# Tried both enabled and disabled here but to no avail.    
Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

### Update

People have commented I shouldn't have all four monitors absolutely positioned, but that is completely valid.  It's recommended against if you have resolutions that can change or just because if you're not careful you could inadvertently cause screen overlaps or worse  create gaps of 'no man's land' between them making it impossible to get to, but that isn't the case here.  Again, the mouse moves across all monitors as expected.  Plus, even when using relative positioning (e.g. 'LeftOf', 'RightOf') I still have the same issue.

I'm starting to think it's just the massive width that's causing the issue.  Anything over 4000 pixels wide seems to barf and my desktop has 8000.

Comment: Can you post xorg.conf?

Comment: @Karlson, see above.  I also re-wrote the question to better explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like your monitors are configured as seperate X displays instead of as just one.
What you want is TwinView/Xinerama.

May be possible to also configure that via their GUI Tool. I've never used that myself though, so I don't know for sure.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier      "Xinerama"
    Screen          0 "Default Screen[0]" 0 0
    Screen          1 "Default Screen[1]" LeftOf "Default Screen[0]"
    Screen          2 "                 " Above  "                 "
    Screen          3 "                 " Above  "                 "
    InputDevice     "Generic Keyboard"
    InputDevice     "Configured Mouse"
    Option          "Xinerama"      "on"
EndSection
```

Assuming a non-horizontal Alignment, but from your config I assume that you do have a horizontal alignment. It does make them operate as one screen, but Usually it doesn't care about their size. At least when aligning horizontally.

Comment: I thought Xinerama made all displays operate as a single screen and as such had to have the same resolutions, etc.  In my case I have a center 30" @ 2560x16oo flanked by two 24" @ 1920x1200 on either side, then far-right I have a Cintiq 21UX @ 1600x1200.  With all of that, where the heck will everything go (i.e. the launcher strip, menu bar, system clock, etc.)  Man, even Windows is easier than this!!

Comment: Also, in case it matters, I have dual video cards... two monitors on each.

Comment: Ah, yeah it does.
Take a look at this: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-set-up-multiple-monitors-in-linux/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Isn't that what I already have above though? (I added the conf file to the question.)

Comment: Yeah, and now you still need Xinerama to make all this one desktop instead of 4 seperate ones. See my post above.

Comment: Shouldn't the above change work?

Comment: I assume it would.

Comment: Just re-edited the question with a new `xorg.conf` file that in theory should work, but doesn't.  One or two monitors work.  As soon as I enable a third or more, things get wonky.  Any thoughts? (One other thing... while you were dead-on about the Xinerama, you don't actually need TwinView and actually in my case, can't use it as the screens aren't aligned so the menu gets cut off.  Plus the launcher is always on the left-most screen.)

Comment: The way I understand it TwinView is an alternative solution to Xinerama developed by nVidia (at least in my head there is a bell ringing about nVidia and Xinerama not going well together, in the past).
So Xinerama, as is TwinView, is just a way to stitch together screens to represent one desktop. Now look at that config sample I put up there and compare it to yours. The way I understand it is, that you must tell Xinerama how to position the displays. Try the syntax in my example by saying "ScreenN+1" LeftOf "ScreenN" instead of what you put in there.

Comment: It's not a case of the positioning as even if I use the relative placements, I still have the same issues.  And the difference between Xinerama and TwinView is that TwinView stitches multiple physical screens into one virtual screen, not to be confused with Xinerama which combines multiple X Screens together on a single desktop.

Comment: In other words, if you have a 1024x768 and a 1200x1600 screen side by side, if you use TwinView Ubuntu sees that as a single X Screen with a res of 2224x1600.  The downside is the menubar and such stretches across both physical monitors so if they aren't top-aligned, you will lose the menubar 'off the edges'.  Plus, the launcher is always on the left monitor.  If you instead disable TwinView and use Xinerama, then each monitor will be its own X Screen and therefore will have its own menubar, etc.  You can also use both Xinerama and TwinView at the same time if you have 3+ monitors.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a limitation of Unity's 3D engine. The cards can easily handle the resolution, but Unity seems to choke on anything over about 4000 horizontal pixels.

Comment: That is possible. There might be problems regarding Xinerama and AIGLX.